# Using a ClassName as a parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

I have several classes that contain validation methods in them : ClientValidation, PaymentValidation, etc. The plan is to dynamically build a list of methods that I would use to validate a record. To do this I need to be able to get a list of the methods contained within each class.  To do that I have written the following line:

```
var methods = typeof( ClientValidation ).GetMethods();
```

This works great if all my methods were under the ClientValidation class, but they are not. What I want to be able to do is be able to dynmically pass in the class name so the line could look more like:

```
var dynamicClassName = GetClassNameMethod();

var methods = typeof( dynamicClassName ).GetMethods();
```

Is this possible?   How would I do this?

Comment: Side note: for future question instead of variations of "searched alot" please add links to articles/questions you've found with one line description why particular solution did not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var methods = Type.GetType(full_class_name).GetMethods();
```

Where `full_class_name` is the full class name (with the namespace). For example: "ConsoleApplication1.Class1".

If you want to use the class name without the namespace (e.g. "Class1"), you can search the assembly for such class like this:

```
var methods = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == class_name).GetMethods();
```

Where `class_name` is the class name like "Class1".

Comment: I could not make this work or any of the other methods and I just realized why - The methods are in a different assembly and not in the current one that is executing.  When I used this in the right location it worked like a charm.  This is why I had no luck with the other duplicates.  Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: If you know some class (e.g. `Class2`) in the other assembly, you can use `typeof(Class2).Assembly` to get that assembly.